# How To Run Multiple Code ffmpeg in Macbook Terminal Using bat file?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have a problem to run bat file in Macboook Terminal. I created file bat that has code below.

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4    -vf hflip -c:a copy output1.mp4
ffmpeg -i input2.mp4    -vf hflip -c:a copy output2.mp4
ffmpeg -i input3.mp4    -vf hflip -c:a copy output3.mp4
```

If I run that bat file in window Command Promt I will get three outputs(output1,output2,output3). It work fine.

But If I run it in terminal Mackbook by drag that file to terminal I get only output3. I don't know why in Macbook It works only the last code.

Please Anyone knows about this help me. I was stuck a few days already.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I'm surprised you get anything at all; Macs use bash, not batch. They're completely different languages. I suppose it happens to work through sheer dumb luck since all you have are calls to external programs, but your entire premise is wrong and you can't find anything because you're looking at the wrong language.

Comment: I wonder if the line ends could be a problem too; Windows and Mac use different ones

Comment: @SomethingDark, Thank you for your reply. So what file should I create to run that code in Mac? Please Help Me!

Comment: @sabik So, do you any solution sir? Please help me?

Comment: Sorry; just that one potential problem to check...